# Google App Script to Break out Query Parameters in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, split, query-string

I have a Google Sheet with 100 https request URLs with query parameters. The URLs look like this:
https://122.2o7.net/b/ss/ryan1/1/JS-2.0.0/s12345678?AQB=1&ndh=1&pf=1&t=6%2F9%2F2018%208%3A48%3A34%206%20360&ts=1538837314190&vid=test&fid=1w23232-erwwwre&ce=UTF-8&ns=ryan&pageName=ryan%3Atest%3Apage&g=https%3A%2F%2Fryanpraski.com%2F&cc=USD&ch=home&events=event1&c1=D%3Dv1&v1=evar1value&h1=hier1value&v20=evar20value&bh=8&AQE=1

I want to use Google App Script to break out the query parameters and put them neatly into the Google Sheet like this:
[image]

I got as far as the code below to break query string and split the query string parameters by the & delimiter, but I am not sure what to do next.

A couple cases that I need to consider as well.

1. There could be URLs with more or fewer parameters than my sample URL, but there will always be some overlay. I want to have the column headers automatically update.
2. There could be values like c1=D%3Dv1 where the decoded value is c1=D=v1

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function test() {
var url = "https://122.2o7.net/b/ss/ryan1/1/JS-2.0.0/s12345678?AQB=1&ndh=1&pf=1&t=6%2F9%2F2018%208%3A48%3A34%206%20360&ts=1538837314190&vid=test&fid=1w23232-erwwwre&ce=UTF-8&ns=ryan&pageName=ryan%3Atest%3Apage&g=https%3A%2F%2Fryanpraski.com%2F&cc=USD&ch=home&events=event1&c1=D%3Dv1&v1=evar1value&h1=hier1value&v20=evar20value&bh=8&AQE=1";
var cleanUrl = decodeURIComponent(url);
var params = cleanUrl.split('?')[1];
var s = params;
var t = s.split('&');
var output = [];
t.forEach(function(q) {
    output.push([q]);
});
Logger.log(output);
```

}

Comment: In order to put the values to Spreadsheet, you can use [``setValues(values)``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). ``values`` is 2 dimensional array. If you want to parse the query from several URLs and put the values, please be careful the length of each element of ``values``. The length of each element is required to be the same. About ``c1=D=v1``, if ``c1`` and ``D=v1`` are key and values, respectively, I think that you can split at the first ``=``. If this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code breaks out the query parameters and puts them into a specific sheet. It also addresses a couple of possible scenarios:
1 There is no match for an existing code. In that case, a space is entered as a place holder.
2 The URL includes codes not included in the existing list. In that case, the "new" code(s) are added to the list, and their values are recorded also.
3 As the questioner pointed out, some URL parameters include multiple "Equals" signs ("="). [`Split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) can't be used in this case because though a parameter can be used to limit the number of split found, the left-over text is not returned in the new array. So I used [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) (which returned the index of the first occurrence of searchValue) and [`subString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to calculate the two parts of the URL component.

I assumed that the existing list of codes was in Row1, so I created a `NamedRange` to be able to manage them. If the code finds URL parameters that don't find a match with the codes in the Named Range, then the NamedRange is deleted and re-created to include the "new" codes.

The code outputs results to the "third sheet" (ss.getSheets()[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf);) in the spreadsheet; this is something that can be changed. 
The last row containing data is determined, and the results of the analysis are set in the following row

Note: the url is hard coded.

---

```
function so_52825789() {


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var datasheet = ss.getSheets()[2];

    // the codes are in Row1 in a Named Range called DataVariables
    var urlvars = ss.getRangeByName('DataVariables').getValues();

    // get the number of Columns for the Named Range
    var datalen = urlvars[0].filter(String).length;
    //Logger.log("Number of columns of codes = "+datalen); //DEBUG

    //get the last row of containing data
    var lastvals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    var lastrow = lastvals.filter(String).length;
    //Logger.log("the last row is "+lastrow);// DEBUG

    // Get the url
    var url = "https://122.2o7.net/b/ss/ryan1/1/JS-2.0.0/s12345678?AQB=1&ndh=1&pf=1&t=6%2F9%2F2018%208%3A48%3A34%206%20360&ts=1538837314190&vid=test&fid=1w23232-erwwwre&ce=UTF-8&ns=ryan&pageName=ryan%3Atest%3Apage&g=https%3A%2F%2Fryanpraski.com%2F&cc=USD&ch=home&events=event1&c1=D%3Dv1&v1=evar1value&h1=hier1value&v20=evar20value&bh=8&AQE=1&ejb=1";

    // Javascript function to remove the URL encoded charaters
    var cleanUrl = decodeURIComponent(url);

    // get the URL variables (the second half of the split)
    var params = cleanUrl.split('?')[1];
    var s = params;

    // get the specific query variables by spliting on "&"
    var t = s.split('&');

    // get the number of query variables
    var tlen = t.filter(String).length;

    // setup some variables for use later
    var output = [];
    var mismatchcode = [];
    var mismatchdata = [];
    var tcount = [];
    var nomatch = 0;
    var ttest = 0;
    var ztest = 0;

    // Loop through the known codes from the Named Range
    for (i = 0; i < datalen; i++) {

        // set a variable value so that you can count how many named codes were found
        ttest = 1;

        // Start a loop though the query variables in the URL
        for (z = 0; z < tlen; z++) {

            // get the position of the Equals sign "="; there may be more than one but we only want the first one.
            var n = t[z].indexOf("=");
            if (n > 0) {
                //var result="Equals appears at position = "+(n+1)+" (actual value = "+n+")";
                //Logger.log(result);

                //get the length of the element
                var nstr = t[z].length;
                //Logger.log("Length = "+nstr);  //DEBUG

                // break the element into two halves. The first half is the "Code" and the second half is the "value"
                var code = t[z].substring(0, n);
                var codevalue = t[z].substring((n + 1), nstr);
                //Logger.log("z = "+z+", code is = "+code+", and the value is "+codevalue); // DEBUF
            }

            // test to whether there is a match between the Named Range Code and the URL 
            if (urlvars[0][i] == code) {

                // set the variable to note a match was detected.
                ttest = 0;
                // push the code value into an array
                output.push(codevalue);
                // push the Named range code ID onto an array
                tcount.push(z);
                //Logger.log("Match "+urlvars[0][i]+" = "+code); //DEBUG
            }


        } // end of the URL variables loop

        // having looped through the URL variables, test to see whether there was a match
        // if not (ttest still equals One) then put an empty string in the output array, so ensure that every code has a value
        // and keep count of the number of "nomatches"
        if (ttest == 1) {
            output.push(" ");
            Logger.log("No match for " + urlvars[0][i]);
            nomatch = nomatch + 1;
        }
    } // end of the Named Range loop

    // create an array for 2d format
    var outeroutput = [];
    // put the loop array into the blank array. The result is a 2d array that can be read by the Google sheets script.
    outeroutput.push(output);
    //  For the NamedRange analysis, we can now set the values from the loop
    var targetrange = datasheet.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1, 1, datalen);
    targetrange.setValues(outeroutput);
    //Logger.log("targetrange = "+targetrange.getA1Notation()); //DEBUG



    // count how matches were found for URL variables
    var tcountlen = tcount.filter(String).length;
    // compare the number of variables in the URL with the number of matches. 
    // If there is a difference, then we need to loop through the URL variables, find the ones that didn't match and do stuff with them.
    if ((tlen - tcountlen) > 0) {
        // starp loop for URL variables
        for (z = 0; z < tlen; z++) {
            // set the variable to detect whether or not a a match was made.
            ztest = 1;
            // Repeat the process of splitting the component code and value
            var n = t[z].indexOf("=");
            if (n > 0) {
                // get the length of the variable
                var nstr = t[z].length;
                // get the componet parts
                var code = t[z].substring(0, n);
                var codevalue = t[z].substring((n + 1), nstr);
                //Logger.log("z = "+z+", code is = "+code+", and the value is "+codevalue); //DEBUG
            }

            // start the loop for thecodes in the NamedRange
            for (i = 0; i < datalen; i++) {

                // If there's a match, chnage the value of the 'match testing' varuable
                if (urlvars[0][i] == code) {
                    ztest = 0;
                }
            } // end of the loop for NamedRange codes

            // if there hasn't been match, then
            // push the url variable code and value onto some respective arrays
            if (ztest == 1) {
                mismatchcode.push(code);
                mismatchdata.push(codevalue);
            }
        } // end of the URL variables loop


        //Logger.log("Code fields = "+datalen+", data fields = "+tlen);// DEBUG
        //Logger.log("Total no-matches for codes = "+nomatch);  // DEBUG
        // Logger.log("Total no-matches for URL fields = "+(tlen-tcountlen)); //DEBUG

        // So, what shall we do if there the number of variables in the NAMED RANGE does equal the number of variables 
        //  if((tlen-tcountlen) !=0){

        // These rows are just for DEBUG assignstance.
        // for (i=0;i<(tlen-tcountlen);i++){ //DEBUG
        // Logger.log("URL field not found: code = "+mismatchcode[i]+", value = "+mismatchdata[i]); //DEBUG
        // } //DEBUG

        // create the arrays to act as 2d
        var outermismatchcode = [];
        var outermismatchdata = [];

        // Push the mismatch arrays to the create the 2d arrays
        outermismatchcode.push(mismatchcode);
        outermismatchdata.push(mismatchdata);

        // Identify the range for the addition URL Codes and values
        // set the respective values
        var extraurlcoderange = datasheet.getRange(1, datalen + 1, 1, (tlen - tcountlen));
        extraurlcoderange.setValues(outermismatchcode);
        var extraurldatarange = datasheet.getRange(lastrow + 1, datalen + 1, 1, (tlen - tcountlen));
        extraurldatarange.setValues(outermismatchdata);

        // We want to add the "new" codes found in the URL to the Named Range.
        // Start by deletinging the existing NamedRange
        ss.removeNamedRange("DataVariables");

        // Define the parmeters for a new range.
        // The main thing is that we need to add more columns
        var newnamedrange = datasheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, (datalen + (tlen - tcountlen)))

        // So, Create a new NamedRange using the same name as before.
        ss.setNamedRange('DataVariables', newnamedrange);

        // The following lines are just to check that everything worked OK
        // var rangeCheck = ss.getRangeByName("DataVariables"); // DEBUG
        // if (rangeCheck != null) { //DEBUG
        //  Logger.log("Columns in the new named range = "+rangeCheck.getNumColumns());//DEBUG
        // }  ,//DEBUG
        // var rangeCheckName = rangeCheck.getA1Notation();  //DEBUG
        // Logger.log("the new named range is  = "+rangeCheckName);//DEBUG    


    } // end of the loop to identify URL variables that didn't match a code in the NamedRange    
}
```

---

Note the addition value of the c1 code includes the relevant equals sign. Also the URL includes an additional parameter ("ejb=1") that is not in the existing list; this code and its value are added to the spreadsheet, and the NamedRange now includes the "new" code.
[image: so_52825789 screenshot]

Comment: Great. If I have the URLs in another sheet called URLs in column A range (A:A). How can I update the URLs variable so I is not hard coded. I tried `var url = ss.getSheetByName('URLS').getRange("A:A");` but get an error on line 31 "Cannot call method "split" of undefined. It looks like params and s are undefined and clearnURL is a "Range" in the debug. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @RyanPraskievicz `getRange` only returns the range. You need to do `get values` too. And even then, it returns a 2d array so the value might be expressed as values[0][0]. The  [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column) has an example. But overall, you've got the idea.

Comment: @RyanPraskievicz I meant to say that if you like the answer then, as the questioner, there's also a process for you to "accept" it as your preferred answer.